# Java - LinkedList push() pop() implies it is a stack, not a queue?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue

In my data structures class, I learned that a `LinkedList` is a queue. Like a line in real life, the first person who gets into the line will be the first person who leaves. Makes sense. As seen below, a `ListedList` implements a `Queue` which has a FIFO (first in first out) procedure.

But if you look at the descriptions for the methods `push(E)` and `pop()`, they read as follows:

push(E)

> Pushes an element onto the stack represented by this list. In other words, inserts the element at the front of this list.

pop()

> Pops an element from the stack represented by this list. In other words, removes and returns the first element of this list.

That's.... not a queue. That's a stack. The first element that goes into the LinkedList via `push` cannot be accessed by `pop` until every element added after it has been `pop()`'ed.

Why is this? I get that LinkedLists can be both used as a stack (if you only use `addFirst(E)` and `removeFirst()`) and can be used as a queue (if you only use `addFirst(E)` and `removeLast()` or vice versa) so why is it like this? I feel like `pop()` should remove and return the last element, OR `push(E)` should add the element at the end of the `LinkedList`. Then it would make more sense.

TLDR: Why does `LinkedList`'s `push` and `pop` imply it works as a stack when `LinkedList` actually implements `Queue` instead.

[image]

Comment: A list is neither inherently a stack nor a queue, but it can be used as either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Push()` and `pop()` are by convention operations related to `Stacks` (`Deque`, more specifically in this context) and that's why you should expect your `LinkedList` to work that way when you use those method.
If you want your `LinkedList` to work as a `Queue` instead (it implements the `Queue` interface) the methods you want to use (as stated in the Documentation) are `add()` and `remove()`.

[See LinkedList Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Answer (score 2):

The methods (`push()` and `pop()`) you are mentioning are from the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface, which is also implemented by [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). The Javadoc for `Deque` states:

> A linear collection that supports element insertion and removal at both ends. The name deque is short for "double ended queue" and is usually pronounced "deck". Most Deque implementations place no fixed limits on the number of elements they may contain, but this interface supports capacity-restricted deques as well as those with no fixed size limit.

In other words, it is not the same as a regular queue.

If you really want to use `LinkedList` as a queue, you should assign the variable to that interface:

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Doing this, you would only be able to use the `queue` as a, well, queue. This interface defines, among other methods, `add()` and `remove()`, which are used to add and remove elements from the queue.

Comment: Ohhhh I forgot you could do `Interf x = new ClassWhoImplementsInterf();`. What happens when you do `Apple x = new SuperApple();`? (assuming `SuperApple` is a subclass of `Apple`) Can you only use methods from `Apple` in that case, or this trick only works for interfaces?

Comment: It basically works the same way with classes, abstract or concrete. Although that would be a totally different discussion, and should probably be asked as a different question if you want further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the class diagram a `LinkedList` is both a `List` **AND** a `Deque`.

The `Deque` interface defines a "double ended queue" abstraction that can act as either a FIFO (i.e. stack) or a LIFO (i.e. a `Queue`) ... at the same time.  From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html):

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy `Stack` class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque.

The `push` and `pop` operations come from the FIFO side of the `Deque` API.

---

> `LinkedList` - `push()`, `pop()` implies it is a stack, not a queue?

Logically speaking, that is not correct.

- You are correct that `push()` and `pop()` implies a stack.
- However, only the **absence** of `add()` and `remove()` would imply NOT a queue.

FIFO and LIFO functionality are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` is a double ended queue ([`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)) and therefore you can add and remove elements from both ends. Also it implements `List`, which allows you to modify parts in the middle too.

This doesn't change the fact that it can be used as a queue by using `add`/`offer` and `poll` /`remove`.

Comment: Are `pop` and `push` terms specifically used for stacks? I don't want to ever name one of my data structure's methods `pop` and then suddenly realize that convention states that `pop` should be a method which removes the first element or something.

Comment: @Hatefiend AFAIK push/pop is just used for stacks (or stack-like behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

A single-linked list makes an excellent stack, but only  a very bad queue. Only a double-linked, double-rooted list is well suited as a queue.

A single-linked list allows O(1) insertion and removal at the head only (i.e. stack operation).

Finding the tail element requires you traverse all the list in O(n) (unless it is double-rooted). Removing the tail requires you to modify the second-to-last element. To make this efficient, you need a double-linked-list (double-rooted is not enough to make thid O(1))

But of course any double-linked list inherits the ability to function as a stack from single-linked lists. You can still access the head in O(1). So **there is no contradiction in something being a queue *and* a stack**.

Note that in Java reality, because of the overhead, `LinkedList` is almost always a bad idea. Neither for a stack nor a queue it should be used, but you should always prefer array-based implementations unless you are often inserting or removing objects in the *middle* of large lists, too. (Really, benchmark `LinkedList` - it's very slow and memory expensive).